# CFLint - Global Variable warning

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc, cflint

I'm using the VS Code editor. And I have installed CFLint on my editor. On Application.cfc I see 'Identifier this is global, referencing in a CFC or function should be avoided.cflint(GLOBAL_VAR)' message when I mouse over into this scope.

Please explain this little bit elaborate. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The `this` scope in ColdFusion is equivalent to Java's `public <type> <variable>` declaration, a.k.a. "public fields". You can read and write these variables from anywhere, which is usually a bad thing (violates OOP encapsulation, is not thread-safe etc.).

This is also true for components (classes) in ColdFusion. However, the `Application.cfc` is a special case where this linter warning doesn't make any sense since "Application" is a singleton handled by ColdFusion and you cannot encapsulate it's configuration fields that reside in `this`.

Conclusion: Ignore this message in `Application.cfc` for all built-in fields, but follow it in every other `.cfc` file.

*(You might want to [report this to the linter's maintainer](https://github.com/cflint/CFLint/issues).)*

Comment: What is the difference here with "this" being the reference to the current instance of the object. When i dump "this" it gives the current component. I am really confused. Can you please guide me?

Comment: The `this` scope in CF components is basically just a struct (`Map`). Dumping a component reveals this map, so you will be able to see all public fields and also all public methods, inluding the `init` constructor. Try `structKeyArray(yourComponent)` to see what I mean. On the other hand there is the `variables` scope, which is the private access. You won't be able to expose those fields, unless you have a public function that returns `variables` (it's also a struct btw.). Don't get fooled by `cfdump`, it tends to be fancy around these things, while in reality it's much simpler.